# using reflection for this, is there another way?

Tags: .net, reflection, .net-3.5

I have a list of keyvaluepair(string,string) first string is something like class.property, second string is the value to assign to that class.property.

I'm currently looping through that list and by using reflection I set every value.

it work, but my question is there a faster way to do this?

Comment: If all you have is 2 strings I think reflection is all you can use here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using the same property repeatedly (e.g. against a variety of target objects), it's faster to [build a delegate out of the setter](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2008/08/09/making-reflection-fly-and-exploring-delegates.aspx) using `Delegate.CreateDelegate` and use that. However, I'd only do that when I'd profiled it and found that this was a bottleneck. It happened to make a big difference against my protocol buffer implementation, but that really needs to be as fast as possible, so I'm happy to apply a bit of micro-optimisation.

Comment: sadly, my list of keyvaluepair can contains nearly a hundred of item and each one is calling one unique class.property. that link is bookmarked because I'm pretty sure that I'm going to use it later on, thanks

Comment: If you're only going to use each property once, then doing it directly with reflection is going to be about as fast as it gets.

Comment: you got the green check for the comment above :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to set the same property, or properties on the same type, more than once, cache your Type and PropertyInfo's. It is very easy stuff to cache - and examining the types is what typically takes the time in reflection scenarios.

If you can use C# 4 for this, you might be able to come up with a faster solution using [*dynamic*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736(VS.100).aspx). (I have seen the .NET 3.5 tag, just thought I would mention it).

Comment: Dynamic won't (easily) work here - dynamic typing in C# 4 lets you easily use a name which is known at compile-time against a type which doesn't statically export it - but you'd have to do a fair amount of work to do this against a name which is only available via a string. Admittedly you could create a Python script and then run it :)